# ¿Cómo detectar error al iniciar la aplicacion?

Tags: eventos, excepciones, vb, events, forms-events

Podrían ayudarme,

Les explico mi situación, tengo una aplicación WinForms desarrollada en VB.
Cuando hago pruebas desde el IDE la aplicación se ejecuta sin problemas.
Pero cuando la publico y la instado en un ordenado o computadora esta no abre.

Me dicen que puedo hacer un control de excepciones globales en el AplicationEvent.vb pero no se como se haría esto.

Estaré atento,

Gracias.

Comment: Deberías publicar al menos el código de la clase que representa el punto de inicio de tu aplicación, o especificar bajo qué condiciones se ejecuta la misma una vez instalada: privilegios de usuarios, si modificaste algún permiso sobre los Assemblies de la misma, ....

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el log o algo que tengas asi, como la salida de la consola, yo no codifico en vb, pero supongo que si en tu maquina funciona y en otra no, debe ser alguna `dependencia` faltante o algo parecido.

saludos.